# Got a project , but am lost on how to do it 

Tags: php

Thanks to a well made personal php project, I got an offer to do a paid php project on a freelancer site. Trouble is I am lost on how to proceed :( .
Could someone guide one what is to be done here? would really really appreciate it.

My understanding of the project :

Step1 . It involves making a tool that 'goes' to a webpage(with a userid of a browser) > sets a a cookie(plaintext) > sends the cookie to the server > goes to a final page(this page requires that  plaintext cookie) .

step2: The final page has a search form . The use of my tool would be to enter search terms in this form and extract and parse the resultant html data into a mysql database .

Questions:

1. can this be done using php ? if so what am I looking at here. I know how to do php programming from the point of view of the server , (setcookie,getcookie , send html pages) , but here I would be the client.
2. any other suggestions please

Thanks

Comment: *would my client be expecting a webpage where they can enter the info or a command line php script ?* How can we know? **Ask your client!** This should actually be part of the project description or requirements specification.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566575/how-to-evaulate-the-design-of-a-brand-new-application-which-falls-into-fairly-unf/4566754#4566754

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since step 2 involves having a search page on a web server, I'm guessing the client would also like step 1 to be able to run without use of the command line. However, you should really just ask and find out for sure!

I suggest you look at the [cURL](http://php.net/cURL) library. You will be able to set cookies and have the script navigate to the webpage, along with that data. You might want to have a [look at this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html) if you're doing searching in a MySQL database.

Comment: Thanks, curl is exactly what I wanted.